# Was the Spectreman End Credits Background ever Released as a Poster or Full Image?

Tags: spectreman

In the classic *Spectreman* Japanese action series, the end credits roll while a huge poster of an epic fight between Spectreman and a dragon(?) roll, showing Dr. Gori, Karas, amidst a wrecked city.

I tried, googled, and busted my fingers trying to find that image in high resolution, but to no avail.

I even tried some searches in Japanese, but that went to nothing really.

This YouTube video shows the closing credits:

A small excerpt of said image can be found here:

[image: ED image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where the image came from originally, but here a full view of it from a more recent reprint of a 1970s fan publication.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. What do the Japanese bits say?

Comment: @Valorum 怪獣 (*kaijyuu*, monster) and 創刑号 (*soukeigou*, creator's name  (literally))

Comment: Also, reverse searching this image gave result to "*KAIJU P-Pro Fan Club Booklet*"